# Error when check point inside polygon using STGeomFromText

Tags: sql-server, geospatial

I run this query in sql server 2012

```
DECLARE @thePolygon GEOGRAPHY, @point GEOGRAPHY;
SET @thePolygon = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-107 37,-106 37,-106 36,-107 37))', 4326);
SET @point = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(-1 0)', 4326);
SELECT @thePolygon.STIntersects(@point)
```

This polygon is an area in USA, point is in the sea. But STIntersects function still return true. 
I don't know why but i choose many difference point in anywhere on earth, this function still return true. 
Please help me!

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you reverse the list of coordinates? Bear in mind that a shape on a sphere (the earth) just *divides* the sphere into two regions. Which one is "inside" or "outside" of that shape needs additional information. For SQL Server, the additional information is the ["left-hand rule"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much. It's work perfectly.